# Android studio cannot read the fragment_main.xml

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

the code is locating the fragment_main but i guess android studio cant find the xml file...
also i already tried to synchronize, Apply changes and reset activity, delete fragment_main and add it again, and reinstall and restart app.... nothing seems to work.
[image]

Comment: Try pressing Gradle Sync button (it's the elephant icon on the top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to import  the com.yourpackagename.R in your fragment class and see is still getting error, also try to invalidate cache and restart Android studio

Comment: invalidate cache and restart did all the work thank you for your help.